# Pause Perl script until an outside program is finished

Tags: c#, perl

I code in C# so I don't know much about perl, but I would like to run the code below and have the perl script wait until myprogram.exe is finished before continuing in the script. After a little research I found that the system function in perl should wait for the process to finish before continuing

```
    my $cmd = '\\\serverpath\Shared\myprogram.exe ';
    my $result = system("start /LOW $cmd pram1");

    my $cmd2 = '\\\serverpath\Shared\openPDF.pdf ';
    my $result2 = system("start /LOW $cmd2 ");
```

Then after no luck with the system function, I thought the problem was that myprogram (wrote in c#) doesn't return a value so I changed it to something like whats below, but the perl script still continues right after it calls myprogram.exe

```
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Run_Main();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {              
            sendEmail();
            return 1;
        }           
    }
```

Comment: I don't know windows but might `start` be causing the command to run in the background?

Comment: You need to show us how you are calling the perl script from your C# code. The C# code posted is next to useless in terms of identifying a potential solution.

Comment: @Daniel Kelley The c# code isn't calling the perl script, its the other way around, the perl script runs and calls the c# program (myprogram.exe)

Comment: Ah! Apologies - I completely misread the question.

Comment: @RobEarl Man I think you got it, I knew it would be simple

Comment: Excellent, be sure to post the working version in an answer

Comment: From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126410, the `/wait` flag may also have helped.

Comment: yeah I tried that originally, then changed it. My c# code could of stayed a void as well, I was just looking for a complex answer when it was just a lack of knowledge in perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Luk6e discovered `start` was running the command in the background causing `system` to not wait. Launch the command without `start`:

```
my $cmd = '\\\serverpath\Shared\myprogram.exe ';
my $result = system("$cmd pram1");

my $cmd2 = '\\\serverpath\Shared\openPDF.pdf ';
my $result2 = system("$cmd2 ");
```

or pass the [`/wait`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126410) flag:

```
my $cmd = '\\\serverpath\Shared\myprogram.exe ';
my $result = system("start /wait /LOW $cmd pram1");

my $cmd2 = '\\\serverpath\Shared\openPDF.pdf ';
my $result2 = system("start /wait /LOW $cmd2 ");
```

> /w[ait] Does not return until the other program exits.